# TCP Port 27015 only listening localhost

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04

I am running a private server on Ubuntu 16.04. I need to open up specific ports to accecpt traffic from other IPs.

Bit of background, this is a private game server running CS:GO. The server is running fine, and I can play on it, but in order to use RCON within the game, TCP port 27015 needs to be open on the server.

I have configured other ports fine on the server, but when attempting to open this specific port, it seems to only be listening on localhost:

[image: openports]

Does anyone know why this is is, and how I can get this port to listen to any IP? When I added the ports as UDP, they seem fine. Please let me know if this is to vaugue, or need more info.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that it is specified in the configuration of the service itself (CS:GO) where it listens. At the moment it listens on the TCP (localhost) and UDP (all IPv4 inerfaces)

Comment: Got it, thank you. I did have to sepcify the IP range within the application.

Answer (score 1):

The port is now open. I had to specify `-ip xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx` within `csgo.service`, which is in `/lib/systemd/system/csgo.service`.

In my case, I added `-ip 0.0.0.0.` which opened it up correctly, and users can use RCON from within the game.

Many thanks